# Gradle is stuck at downloading NDK

Tags: android

> Warning:
> unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements
> are <{}codename>,<{}api-level> Checking the license for package NDK
> (Side by side) 21.4.7075529 in
> C:\Users\userhome\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses License for package
> NDK (Side by side) 21.4.7075529 accepted. Preparing "Install NDK (Side
> by side) 21.4.7075529 (revision: 21.4.7075529)". <======-------> 50%
> CONFIGURING [27m 42s]
>
> > :app

This is what i get, i waited almost 30 minutes but nothing. I have downloading it in Android Studio, but no success.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For future reference, this is a step by step approach to install NDK from Android Studio:

1. With a project open, click Tools > SDK Manager.
2. Click the SDK Tools tab.
3. Select the Show Package Details checkbox.

Select the NDK (Side by side) checkbox and the checkboxes below it that correspond to the NDK versions you want to install.

I was getting this line in terminal:

> Install NDK (Side by side) 21.4.7075529 (revision: 21.4.7075529)

[image]

Comment: If you use an M1 chip, you should check `"24.0.8215888"`. Or better look at `android/build.gradle` to see which `ndkVersion` you need.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error in react-native . I simply install NDK from android studio and it worked . Make sure that you download the specific version which is display to you else it will not work . First i downloaded the latest version it didnt worked, but after i installed the specific version display , it worked fine .